# .RU. Ребята. ну исправьте вы русский язык на странице России

Tags: elementary-website

elementary-website
на главной странице "The fast, open, and privacy-respecting replacement for Windows and macOS" и в заголовке

на странице установки https://elementary.io/ru/docs/installation#creating-an-installation-medium часть перевода так же отсутствует

Answer (score 0):

I use *Google translate* for understand your message.

If I understand you need better translate in Ruissian in specific webpage, I think this link can help you:

https://elementary.io/ru/docs/translation-guide#translation-guide

Comment: спасибо что воспользовались гуглом для перевода. Вы всё правильно поняли. И вы всё верно указали. Я зарегистрировался в этой системе, и там есть "главная страница", есть так же несколько вариантов перевода (другими людьми). Но почему тогда модератор не может "одобрить" один из вариантов??

Comment: For the translation @RomanGalkin went on the link I gave him. Unfortunately RomanGalkin I could not answer your new question because I do not know how it is moderated by the team of elmentary OS. Maybe if one of them goes through here he can answer you. Good luck